# Regression ANN getting high root mean squared error values after re scaling dataset

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow, regression, dataset

I have a data set on predicting solar power generation, I am getting root mean squared loos of 0.3196 on training set on scaled values, **but when I inverse transform them my loss rises to 298 on training and 488 on test set. but my r2scores are .883 and .69 on tests and training sets.** R2 scores seems acceptable but why i am getting large value of error.

Here is my code:

```
    data_path = r'drive/My Drive/Proj/S.P.F./solarpowergeneration.csv'
    dts = pd.read_csv('solarpowergeneration.csv')
    dts.head()
    X = dts.iloc[:, :-1].values
    y = dts.iloc[:, -1].values
    print(X.shape, y.shape)
    y = np.reshape(y, (-1,1))
    y.shape
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)
   
   from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
   sc_X = StandardScaler()
   X_train = sc_X.fit_transform(X_train)
   X_test = sc_X.transform(X_test)

   # outcome scaling:
   sc_y = StandardScaler()
   y_train = sc_y.fit_transform(y_train)    
   y_test = sc_y.transform(y_test)


def get_spfnet():
  ann = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

  ann.add(Dense(X_train.shape[1], activation='relu'))
  ann.add(BatchNormalization())
  ann.add(Dense(32, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)))
  ann.add(BatchNormalization())
  ann.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)))
  ann.add(BatchNormalization())

  ann.add(Dense(1))
  ann.compile(loss='mse',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError()])
  return ann

spfnet = get_spfnet()
#spfnet.summary()
hist = spfnet.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=32, validation_data=(X_test, y_test),epochs=250, verbose=2)
```

the accuracy and loss graphs are

```
plt.plot(hist.history['root_mean_squared_error'])
plt.plot(hist.history['val_root_mean_squared_error'])
plt.title('Model error')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('error')
plt.show()
```

[image: rsme plot]

[image: rsme and r2score]

what changes are needed to improve my model

dataset:
[image] [image]

[***colab link of code***](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1WR3l6eB8a0AWiqOdzpa4WCGXAW1P_aKl?authuser=5)

Comment: Contrary to metrics like classification accuracy which are expressed in percentages, no value of RMSE can be considered as "low" or "high" *in itself*; it critically depends on the **scale** of the dependent variable. If, say, you have a `y` that ranges between 0-500, an RMSE of 298 would indeed seem rather high; but the same RMSE of 298 for a `y` that is in the range of, say, 10,000 - 20,000 would count as rather great!

Comment: So you are saying my is doing a great job and I can conclude my work

Comment: I'm saying to check the RMSE in relation to your outouts `y` and their scale before deciding so.